# Store a list of list on each node of a list

Tags: python, list, data-structures

I wanted to know that is it possible to create a list which can store a list of list on each node.

Basically if there is a list X = [A,B,C,D]

Is it possible that each of A, B , C and D be list of lists of themselves?

Can anyone demonstrate how this can be done?

Comment: Yes: `x = [[[1]], [[2]], [[3]], [[4]]]`

Comment: Lists's can hold any object in python but seems you are looking for a `dict` here

Comment: Do literally mean "list of lists ***of themselves***"?

Comment: Yes, each node in the main list is a list of lists. I am writing the ID3 decision Trees algorithm from scratch and I need to store my left data and right data, which are lists of each in a main list say L.

Comment: @ShekharTanwar What ***specifically*** are you having difficulty with? Creating a list of lists of list is trivially easy (`x = [[[]]]`), so it seems you don't literally mean that. You will need to edit your question and explain your requirements in much more detail if you want to get a useful answer.

Comment: @ekhumoro, I got an answer yesterday from one of the above comments. thanks for the support

Answer (score 3):

Yes, lists can hold other lists. You can use the `append` method of list to add other lists to any list. For example:

```
a_list = []
a_list.append([1,2])
a_list.append([3,4])
print(a_list)
```

which gives us

```
[[1, 2], [3, 4]]
```

Comment: It you can just assign the elements or construct like you would with any other object.